# The Stack Exchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ menu not working on Android browser

Tags: bug, stack-exchange-button, android

Suddenly clicking the dropdown at the top left of Stack Exchange sites will flash the menu but it won't stay open in the default android browser. Anyone else have this problem?

This is on a Transformer Prime tablet running Jellybean using the full non-mobile version of the site.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I can reproduce this, also on a transformer prime using the default browser. You can use Opera, it's worked best for me and is still working. I just tried Firefox too, and it won't let me enter anything in the password box, so Opera seems to be the only choice left.

Comment: Upgraded to jellybean or still on ics?  Wonder if that makes a difference.

Comment: Android version 4.1.1, so Jelly Bean (I believe).